# Limit of the sequence $\left\{ (-1)^n\sin(\frac \pi2 + n\pi)\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I understand that while $n$ is odd, the negatives cancel out, so $a_n$ will always be positive 1 and thus the limit will be 1, but I'm struggling to justify my understanding through work. I've thought of showing through a piecewise function, but I feel like that isn't rigorous justification. How should I show this convergence and limit?

Comment: The justification in your first sentence is fine.  No further "work" is needed.

Comment: Expand $\sin(\pi/2 + n \pi)$ using the sum formula for $\sin(A+B)$ and use the fact that $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$

Answer (score 0):

Simply consider the two seperate cases, n odd, and n even.

n odd $\implies$ $n = 2m + 1$, in which case the expression becomes
$(-1)^{2m+1}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} + (2m+1)\pi) = -\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} + (2m +1)\pi) = -\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})$ (since a $2n\pi$ term in a sin function equates to 0) and $-\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$

n even $\implies n = 2m$ in which case the expression becomes $(-1)^{2m}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2m\pi) =\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2m\pi) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Therefore, for every integer n takes, the value is always the same ($\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$) (considering odd and even cases spans every value n can take)